# Get AuthenticationProperties in current HttpRequest after HttpContext.SignInAsync

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.net Core MVC.  In the login process,  in a POST controller action, I am using HttpContext.SignInAsync with an AuthenticationProperties that contains a JWT access token.  In the same HttpRequest, I cannot refetch those properties to get the access token that was created.

```cs
...
var claimsPrincipal = CreateClaimsPrincipal("userName");

var accessToken = new AuthenticationToken()
{
    Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken,
    Value = TOKEN_VALUE
};
AuthenticationToken[] tokens = { accessToken };

var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
authenticationProperties.StoreTokens(tokens);
authenticationProperties.IsPersistent = true;

// Here we sign in the user
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal, authenticationProperties);

// Afterwards, we cannot access the access token either from
var tokenValueFromGetTokenAsync = HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken)
// Or with
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
var tokenValueFromAuthenticateAsync = result.Properties.GetTokenValue(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
```

Is there a way to set the AuthenticationProperties of the current http request ?
I know I can set the ClaimsPrincipal with

```
HttpContext.user = claimsPrincipal
```

But is there something similar that I can do with AuthenticationProperties.  Something like

```
// I made that part up, would be cool though
HttpContext.Authentication.Properties = authenticationProperties
```

I uploaded a super simple code example of this to github:

[GitHub code example](https://github.com/CurlyFire/TestGetAuthenticationProperties.git)

check the SecurityController Login method decorated with a HttpPost attribute.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to get `authenticationProperties` from `HttpContext` in the same request? Why not access `authenticationProperties` directly?

Comment: The reason is that the login code is in a middleware that is called before the MVC action call.  The user is logged in through the middleware, then the MVC action is called but the AuthenticationProperties is not available.

Comment: I did not want to complicate things in this example with a middleware.  Authentication is already complex in .net core

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `AuthenticationProperties`, try to save it by `options.Events.OnSignedIn` like

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Security/Login");
        options.Events.OnSignedIn = context => {
            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            httpContext.Items["Properties"] = context.Properties;
            httpContext.Features.Set(context.Properties);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

And then retrieve by

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var claimsPrincipal = CreateClaimsPrincipal(model.Name);
        var authenticationProperties = CreateAuthenticationProperties();

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal, authenticationProperties);

        HttpContext.User = claimsPrincipal;

        var properties1 = HttpContext.Features.Get<AuthenticationProperties>();
        var properties2 = HttpContext.Items["Properties"];           

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), nameof(HomeController));
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Another option, you may consider adding a new method which is used to retrieve the properties like:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = CreateClaimsPrincipal(model.Name);
            var authenticationProperties = CreateAuthenticationProperties();

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal, authenticationProperties);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(CheckProperties));
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> CheckProperties()
    {
        await FetchTokenAndVerify();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), nameof(HomeController));
    }
```

Comment: That works fine thanks.  I didn't think to use the OnSignedIn event

Answer (score 8):

There is a much cleaner way to do this...

```
var authFeatures = context.Features.Get<IAuthenticateResultFeature>();
var authProps = authFeatures.AuthenticateResult.Properties;
```

This provides direct access to the `AuthenticationProperties` decrypted from the ticket by the authentication middleware.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: yes, but the AuthenticateResult.Properties dont have any tokens in them...

Comment: a bit unrelated but how does the authneticationproperties relate to the options where they seem somewhat to overlap? 
             builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                        .AddCookie(options =>
                        {
                            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden/";
                        });

Comment: The options are used to generate the auth ticket. When the middleware decrypts the ticket it will have some of the options you’ve set. For example, the expiration timespan will be used to compute an actual expiration date.