# ASP.NET Identity - Get Saved third-party access tokens

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-identity

I have an app that will operate almost entirely on Spotify OAuth, that will have features to alter the playback of your music.

I'm able to get Spotify OAuth working perfectly such that I can log into my app, but after I've logged in, I need access to the current user's spotify access_token so that I can forward it to my spotify requests.

I followed this guide from ms to try to save the tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

And I have tried all these ways to then save that token into the `HttpContext` such that I can access it:

```
            options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
            {
                List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

                tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                {
                    Name = "TicketCreated",
                    Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                });
                var spotifyAccessToken = tokens.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "access_token").Value;
                tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                {
                    Name = "SpofityAccessToken",
                    Value = spotifyAccessToken
                });

//store all the tokens as directed by MS
                ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

//store the properties into the HttpContext in 2 different ways
                ctx.HttpContext.Items["Properties"] = ctx.Properties;
                ctx.HttpContext.Features.Set(ctx.Properties);

//try adding a claim to the user
                ctx.Identity.AddClaims(new[] { new Claim("SpotifyAccessToken", spotifyAccessToken) });

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
```

The problem I'm having is how do I then get this token out? all of these methods are not working:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task Get()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(User);
// try to re-run Authenticate, even though i'm already in an [Authorize] controller
            var res = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();
//props2 does not have the tokens i set
            var props2 = res.Properties;

           //props comes back null
            var props = HttpContext.Features.Get<AuthenticationProperties>();

//claims has no SpotifyAccessToken claim
            var claims = User.Claims.ToList();

            var token = "hard-coded";
//here is where i need the token to then query spotify
            var client = new SpotifyAPI.Web.SpotifyClient(token);
            var res2 = await client.Player.GetCurrentPlayback();
        }
```

I feel like I've tried everything, what am i doing wrong?

This is in a .NET 6 blazor wasm, .net core hosted app.

Also tried the solutions here to no avail [Get AuthenticationProperties in current HttpRequest after HttpContext.SignInAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54202190/get-authenticationproperties-in-current-httprequest-after-httpcontext-signinasyn)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am running up against the same issue.

Comment: @don Nope, sorry

Comment: Same situation here, cannot find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync adds the the authentication tokens in [dbo].[AspNetUserTokens]

External login is where I call it:

```
// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: true, bypassTwoFactor: true);
        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info);
            _logger.LogInformation("{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} provider.", info.Principal.Identity.Name, info.LoginProvider);
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

Later on you can get it by using :

```
            var token = await userManager
            .GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Spotify", "access_token");

        var expiresAtStr = await userManager
            .GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Spotify", "expires_at");
```

Answer (score -1):

If the token is stored in the Cookie then you can access the various tokens using:

```
string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
string idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
string refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");
string tokenType = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("token_type");         
string accessTokenExpire = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
```

However, you can not store data in ctx.HttpContext and assume it will be persisted across requests. either you sign-in the user using the cookie middleware or you store the tokens in the UserSession object.

See this article on how to configure and store data in the session, that will be persisted across requests.

[Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

If you configure it properly, then you can use it like:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("token", token.Trim());
```

Comment: The OP clearly said that the problem is storing the token.

Comment: If you use the built-in OpenIDConnect and Cookie handler middleware, my answer represents the usual way to retrieve the tokens after successful authentication. One alternative is to store the tokens in the User Session object, so its persisted across request. The core point is that you need to either store the tokens in your session cookie or in the backend. I think this would be the simplest approach. do review this article on how to store objects in the session object.